# How can run Binance api in laravel with Controller

Tags: laravel, api, binance

I can't use binance api in laravel

I installed Php binance api from composer require "jaggedsoft/php-binance-api @dev" but examples not working in laravel.I had some errors when I tried.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
class BinanceController extends Controller
{

public function list()
{
    $api = new Binance\API();
    $key = "----";
    $secret = "---";
    $api = new Binance\API($key, $secret);

    $price = $api->price("BNBBTC");
    return $price;

}

}
```

When I runned the route I got this error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Binance\API' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not importing Binance\API correctly. Laravel believes the Binance\Api class is located in the `App\Http\Controllers\Binance` namespace. Which it is not.

Try `$api = new \Binance\API();`

Or put it in your use cases.

`use Binance\API`

I also found [an old wrapper](https://github.com/adman9000/laravel-binance) which you may be able to import if there hasn't been any changes to Binance since but I highly doubt it. Since your case is specific to Laravel, look for a Binance wrapper for Laravel specifically. [Here may contain some useful information on how to use non-laravel packages, with laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/using-non-laravel-composer-package-with-laravel)